# Are value converters instantiated per-binding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, valueconverter

Is a separate WPF value converter object instantiated for each binding that a particular value converter class is used in?

---

I am trying to create a two-way bit-to-boolean value converter. I would like to be able to bind a `bool` property (such as `IsChecked`) to a bit in a value type (like a `ushort`). I'm using the converter's `parameter` arguments to specify the bit. Implementing the ConvertBack() method is easy, but Convert() is little trickier.

In Convert() I need to know what the value of the entire `ushort` is so I can toggle just the single bit I am interested in. I was thinking of just using a member variable in my value converter class to temporarily store this whenever ConvertBack() is called, thus leading to the above question: does each binding get its own value converter instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a converter defined in your resources, it will be shared amongst your properties.

If you need unique converters:
If you create a specific converter for a property, however, it will not be shared.  Either option is workable.  You can even use multiple converters (of the same type, with different keys) in your resources, which will create unique instances.

Comment: Can someone please clarify this answer. There's some typo somewhere which makes this very confusing.

Comment: "If you need unique converters: If you create a specific converter for a property, however, it will not be shared." This does not make any sense. There is something missing isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: @NVM: No.  You can create an instnace of a converter for a specific dependency property.  In this case, it won't be shared between other properties.  If you use a resource, and reference the converter by key, it will be shared.

Comment: Thanks. I finally understood the sentence. English is not my native language :). I think it would be much clearer if you dropped the following "If you need unique converters:"

Comment: I have tried using multiple resources of the same converter type with different keys, but they all still are the same instance. It seems impossible to create different instances.

Comment: @Neo: You can define them inline, instead of in the resources.  If you do, you should get separate instances...

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor and destructor in your converter and set breakpoints within to tell for sure. I just created a simple example and it looks like only one converter was created for my multiple viewmodels that were using the constructor

Comment: I also did this and had the same result--it became obvious that only one converter would be instantiated when I declared it as a single static resource in my XAML.